# Why is the difference between backlinks in Alexa, Google Webmaster Tools and Ahrefs?

Tags: backlinks

I'm a little bit confused between what to choose. The backlink volume showing in Alexa termed as "Site Linking In" and the backlinks showing in Ahrefs have too much difference.

Also, the backlink data showing in Webmaster Tools are too confusing.

I just want to have the simple method by which I can check the backlink data for my website. How, which and when other websites are linking to me, so that I can strategize in a much better way.

Comment: Choose a source to check new backlinks and keep it all the time.

Answer (score 3):

The link counts are different because they have different crawlers to collect the data and they don't all crawl the web in the same way, volume or rate.

Answer (score 1):

These 3 tools have different crawlers or they're programmed differently. I would still put more emphasis on Google's compared to Ahrefs and Alexa.

Answer (score 1):

Well, each one has different algorithms and crawlers, so it's not weird to find them different. You would better put more emphasis on the Webmaster tools backlinks count because this is probably what will matter for Google as a search engine.

Comment: Hi there and welcome aboard. It's an old question already answered. Check questions > newest or unanswered in order to help more efficiently. Regards ;)